# Does Windows file share (samba protocol) have an incremental API?

Tags: windows, samba, inotify

I'd like to query a windows share for "all files added/edited/removed since timestamp `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss`"

Does such a thing exist?

The only thing I know of is `inotify` - is this the only option?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124617/getting-file-create-notifications-for-cifs-mount-in-linux

`inotify` is not really what I want because that is push based when I'm looking for something I call poll.

Kind of sounds like what I'm looking for doesn't exist, but I figured I'd ask here to see if anyone has heard of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently no.

Windows itself (through local disk access) would offer the *USN journal*, which has the ability to query all changes since a specific journal entry index (you would then store the 'current' index along with every backup). However, this is not available via SMB, according to [MS-SMB appendix A section 136](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246806.aspx#Appendix_A_136):

> Windows does not support USN journal calls because they require a volume handle. The following USN journal calls are also failed with STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED.
>
> FSCTL_READ_USN_JOURNAL, FSCTL_CREATE_USN_JOURNAL, FSCTL_QUERY_USN_JOURNAL, FSCTL_DELETE_USN_JOURNAL, FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA

You can also dig through the other SMB messages documented in [MS-SMB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246231.aspx) or [MS-SMB2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246482.aspx) (section 2). I could not find any messages which would search for files in any way except for enumerating a single directory. (In any case this would be somewhat unusual for a filesystem protocol to have...)

Comment: excellent - the `USN journal` might be just what we need. i will look into it